# bash: interpret string variable as file name/path

Tags: string, bash, filenames

My bash script receives a filename (or relative path) as a string, but must then read from that file.  I can only read from a filename if I declare it as a literal directly in the script (without quotes)...which is impossible for arguments since they are implicitly strings to begin with.  Observe:

```
a="~/test.txt"
#Look for it
if [[ -a $a ]] ; then
    echo "A Found it"
else
    echo "A Error"
fi
#Try to use it
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < $a

b='~/test.txt'
#Look for it
if [[ -a $b ]] ; then
    echo "B Found it"
else
    echo "B Error"
fi
#Try to use it
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < $b

c=~/test.txt
#Look for it
if [[ -a $c ]] ; then
    echo "C Found it"
else
    echo "C Error"
fi
#Try to use it
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < $c
```

YIELDS:

```
A Error
./test.sh: line 10: ~/test.txt: No such file or directory
B Error
./test: line 12: ~/test.txt: No such file or directory
C Found it
Hello
```

As stated above, I can't pass a command line argument to the routines above since I get the same behavior that I get on the quoted strings.

Comment: "~/test.txt" and '~/test.txt' stop expansion of the ~ into your home directory.  ~/test.txt works because it is unquoted.  Stop using the ~ notation or stop using quotes....

Comment: If you just use the script's command line argument (`$1`), then everything will work fine because the home directory expansion will have already been done before the script is called.

Comment: @rici Yes, provided that the `~` is not quoted when his script is called from the command line or from another script. It's a different story when his script is called from some other program that passes _a literal_ `~` That would be a mistake that should be fixed in the other program; but if he want's to deal with such a case in his own script, he probably needs `eval`.

Answer (score 58):

This is part of the rules of `~`-expansion. It is clearly stated in the Bash manual that this expansion is not performed when the `~` is quoted.

## Workaround 1

Don't quote the `~`.

```
file=~/path/to/file
```

If you need to quote the rest of the filename:

```
file=~/"path with spaces/to/file"
```

(This is perfectly legal in a garden-variety shell.)

## Workaround 2

Use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

```
file="$HOME/path/to/file"
```

## BTW: Shell variable types

You seem to be a little confused about the types of shell variables.

Everything is a string.

Repeat until it sinks in: **Everything is a string.** (Except integers, but they're mostly hacks on top of strings AFAIK. And arrays, but they're arrays *of strings*.)

This is a shell string: `"foo"`. So is `"42"`. So is `42`. So is `foo`. If you don't need to quote things, it's reasonable not to; who wants to type `"ls" "-la" "some/dir"`?

Comment: `file=~"/path with spaces/to/file"` does not work too. It is necessary to write `file=~/"path with spaces/to/file"`

Comment: @sercxjo for me it works on zsh and doesn't work on bash. I.e. `~/"` is more portable.

Comment: @sercxjo (and Nick) fixed

Comment: Personally I'd flip these recommendations - using `$HOME` is much more consistent and intuitive. `~` should be treated as a convenience only where it works. Jumping through hoops like taking advantage of quoting semantics may "work" but it's brittle and confusing.

Comment: Just to re-highlight the actual issue as stated above 'This is part of the rules of ~-expansion. It is clearly stated in the Bash manual that this expansion is not performed when the ~ is quoted' OP can you maybe put in big text!! @michaelb958-gofundmonica my fix unixpath=${unixpath/\~/$HOME}

Comment: Oh the tilda `~` is not expanded when contained in string

Answer (score 1):

### Final workaround

In complement of [michaelb958's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703720/1765658), I would suggest to use ***pattern substitution***, from bash's ***Parameter Expansion*** (see `man -P'less +/pattern\ substitution' bash`):

```bash
file='~/test.txt'
/bin/ls -1 "${file/#~\//$HOME\/}"   # This should be double-quoted
```

```
/home/user/test.txt
```

Of course this could be used in both way:

```bash
file="$HOME/test.txt"
echo "${file/#$HOME\//\~\/}"
```

```
~/test.txt
```

#### This could be done over an whole *array* too:

```bash
files=(~/*)
echo ${files[0]}
```

```
/home/user/afile.ext
```

```bash
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]/#"$HOME"/\~}"
```

```
~/afile.ext
~/anotherfile.ext
~/...
```

Please note: `${files...}` is **double-quoted** and `$HOME` is  **double-quoted** too! As brace (`{ ... }`) will determine order of expansion, there's no conflict.

### Filtering output by using `sed`:

In order to avoid conflict with any kind of `$HOME` path, I will use `;` as `sed`'s `s` command:

```bash
ls -ld ~/* | sed "s;$HOME;~;"
```

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 user user   4096 12 jui 16:36 ~/Documents
drwxr-xr-x   5 user user   4096 12 jui 16:36 ~/Desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 user user      0 10 sep 12:34 ~/test.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not as glamorous, but worked for me:

```
home_folder="/home/$(logname)"
```

can work from there...

Comment: `$HOME` directory is not necessarly `/home/$USER`!!! Depending on your installation, your `/etc/adduser.conf` or else...