# Is there a way to compile files in src using angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I have the following structure:

```
apps
|-api
  |-src
    |-_migrations
    |-_seeds
      |-dev
      |-test
    |-app
    |-assets
    |-environments
    |-main.ts
  |-tsconfig.app.json
  |-tsconfig.json
```

I am using `ng serve api` to compile and serve `api` which is a NestJS backend. This belongs to a monorepo with an Angular frontend.

The migrations and seeders inside `_migrations` and `_seeds` are in TypeScript. To run them when serving the backend, I need to compile them to JavaScript and locate the compiled files into `dist/apps/api`.

I know I could compile the files with `tsc` before serving, or specify a webpack configuration file in `angular.json`, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible, and just try to use some configuration with `ng`.

I tried adding the paths in the `tsconfig.app.json` which is used in the `angular.json`.

```
// angular.json
"api": {
  "root": "apps/api",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "api",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/api",
        "main": "apps/api/src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": ["apps/api/src/assets"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "inspect": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api:build"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"], // or ["**/*.ts", "src/_migrations/*.ts", "src/_seeds/**/*.ts"] without "files"
  "files": ["src/_migrations/*.ts", "src/_seeds/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Is there a way to compile all the files in `_migrations` and `_seeds` when running `ng serve api` and `ng build api` just switching some configuration or similar?
If not, which would be the simplest webpack configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ref:  https://indepth.dev/configuring-typescript-compiler/

1. TS compiles recursively searches for all files in the root directory
   and sub-directories and compiles them.

   Assuming that you are referencing them , they should compile
2. TS compiler will also compile files that are referenced inside any file from the files list. For example, if main.ts imports exports from a.ts, this file will also be compiled.

> files - tell the compiler to only compile files inside files[] and leave everything else out.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { ... },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "router/b.ts"
  ]
}
```

Instead of listing each file manually if there are more no of files, we can use include option to specify directories using glob-like file patterns
**This will only compile the files in specified directories in include[]**
So in your case this will only compile files in migrations and seeds.

```
{
      "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
        "types": ["node"]
      },
      "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
      "include": ["src/_migrations/*.ts", "src/_seeds/**/*.ts"] 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using `tsc` to compile and it did compile everything, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to compile the files in `_migrations` and `_seeds` using the Angular builder with `ng serve` and `ng build`.

Comment: did you try checking if they are compiling after you enter ng-build command?

Comment: Yes, this is all the output:
```
Starting type checking service...
Using 2 workers with 2048MB memory limit
Hash: dfa3f3187e4fa63feb6d
Built at: 03/22/2020 23:53:28
Entrypoint main = main.js main.js.map
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 13.9 KiB [entry] [rendered]
```

Only `main.ts` is compiled.

Comment: This may help you .https://stackoverflow.com/a/21425873/8029211

Comment: Thanks. If I cannot find a better solution I might use this.