# Error when compiling multiple typescript files

Tags: windows, typescript

I am trying to compile multiple typescript files on a Windows machine from the command prompt (using [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699781/how-can-i-pass-multiple-source-files-to-the-typescript-compiler)).
I have created a file ts.txt with the following content:

```
--module amd
-target ES5
dir *.ts /b /s
```

I then run the following command:

```
tsc @ts.txt
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'dir'.
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '*.ts'.
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '/b'.
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '/s'.
```

If I move the two typescript options to the command line instead of having them in the file, i still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

I am using typescript 1.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the @ parameter is for TypeScript command line options, not Windows CMD line options. I couldn't find a nice concise option of what it actually accepts but I'm gussing it takes the file names from a list and the other tsc options appended. Such as '*.ts  --noImplicitAny'.

I changed the file ts.txt to;

```
--module amd
-target ES5
*.ts
```

and it works, make sure you have .ts files in the wildcard path otherwise it will still bork.

Comment: I tried changing the file as you suggested, and I got the same error, now only for the '*.ts'. If I replace the * with an file name it works.

Comment: Is the file in the current directory? It errored for me when it could not find the ts file.

Comment: Yes the file should contain the exact same arguments as you would pass  otherwise. e.g. if you can do `--module amd --target ES5 *.ts` The file contents should *be the same* and the compilation result will be the same.