# VS2015 Typescript compiler not using the proper config

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I have this Typescript project, that must be compiled to AMD and ES3. When I modify a file and save, the compile on save works just fine. However, when I build my solution, it re-compiles everything to `commonjs` (actually the `--module flag` is not provided so I just assume this is what's selected) and ES5.

I've checked the `.csproj` for the proper config

`<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>`

I've added a `tsconfig.json` at the root and also at the `.ts` files location without any success.

What am I missing? Why is it using the right config for compile on save but not when I'm building the project? Also, randomly I'm getting the "Build: Cannot compile modules unless the `--module` flag is provided." error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273429/cannot-compile-modules-unless-the-module-flag-is-provided/32274106#32274106. There's a bug in VS 2015. So in default scenario it simply ignores you config and uses a default one

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that there is an issue (that is resolved in tsc 1.6) and that the .csproj has to be modified. THe PropertyGroup's condition must be changed to specify one without a platform.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4300

Answer (score 0):

Or you can choose to compile using tsc from the command line directly (which can be installed using `npm install -g typescript`), as long as you have a valid `tsconfig.json` file that specifies the module system and targeted ES version.

Comment: Yes, compiling from the command line would work. I saw a post that would put all *.ts files inside a text file, and then input that file to the compiler. Although, when I debug the solution, it builds the project and overwrites all the compiled files. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16433677/981308)

Comment: I don't think you need to merge all the .ts files. If you don't specify a `files` array in the tsconfig.json, it will implicitly include every .ts file in the same path. If you do specify, it will include only the files you told it to include. The details can be found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: Oh thanks, I missed that part about not specifying a files array. I was under the impression that the tsconfig.json was not being used since it wasn't compiling in the configurations I specified in it (module amd)