# Why won't tsc *.ts work properly?

Tags: typescript

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but when I type `tsc *.ts` into the command prompt it gives me the following error:

```
error TS6053: File '*.ts' not found
```

Is there something I'm just not getting? This is on a Windows10 machine. BTW I can tsc individual scripts, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass multiple source files to the TypeScript compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699781/how-can-i-pass-multiple-source-files-to-the-typescript-compiler)